# i try to scrap data in jobstreet. how to skip data if the data 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I got stuck , when i try to scraping data in jobstreet
I found the data 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' and this make me get some error
how to fix it.
this is the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as sp import requests import openpyxl excel = openpyxl.Workbook()
#print(excel.sheetnames) sheet = excel.active sheet.title = 'jobstreet scrap' sheet.append(['Job ','link job','company','location','published','post'])


keyword = 'sales'

for pages in range(1,10):
    url = 'https://www.jobstreet.co.id/en/job-search/{}-jobs/{}'.format(keyword,pages)
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = sp(page.content,'html.parser')
    job = soup.find('div',class_="sx2jih0 zcydq8bm").find('div',class_='sx2jih0')
    for jobs in job :
            link_job = jobs.find('h1',class_='sx2jih0 zcydq84u _18qlyvc0 _18qlyvc1x _18qlyvc3 _18qlyvca').a.get('href')
            pekerjaan = jobs.find('h1',class_='sx2jih0 zcydq84u _18qlyvc0 _18qlyvc1x _18qlyvc3 _18qlyvca').a.text
            company =  jobs.find('span',class_='sx2jih0 zcydq84u _18qlyvc0 _18qlyvc1x _18qlyvc1 _18qlyvca').text
            location =  jobs.find('span',class_='sx2jih0 zcydq84u _18qlyvc0 _18qlyvc1x _18qlyvc3 _18qlyvc7').span.text
            published = jobs.find('time',class_='sx2jih0 zcydq84u').get('datetime')
            pub = jobs.find('time',class_='sx2jih0 zcydq84u').text
            sheet.append([pekerjaan,link_job,company,location,published,pub])
            print('=====================',pages)
            print("Job : ",pekerjaan,'\n',"link Job : ",link_job,'\n',"company : ",company,'\n',"location",location,'\n',"published : ",pub,'\n',"published at : ",published)

excel.save('jobstreetq.xlsx')
```

this is the error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVlBj.png)

Comment: Please include the error as text, in the question, rather than a screenshot.

Comment: first get `value = find(...)`, next use `if value is not None` and next get `value = value.text`

Answer (score 0):

That's because there is no span tag with that class on that element:

Simply add some logic or add try/except that skips over when an element is not found. Looks like you can find a pattern though that the company class starts with `'sx2jih0 zcydq84u'`. So search for that as opposed to the hard coded `'sx2jih0 zcydq84u _18qlyvc0 _18qlyvc1x _18qlyvc1 _18qlyvca'`

```
import re

keyword = 'sales'

for pages in range(1,10):
    url = 'https://www.jobstreet.co.id/en/job-search/{}-jobs/{}'.format(keyword,pages)
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = sp(page.content,'html.parser')
    job = soup.find('div',class_="sx2jih0 zcydq8bm").find('div',class_='sx2jih0')
    for jobs in job :
            link_job = jobs.find('h1',class_='sx2jih0 zcydq84u _18qlyvc0 _18qlyvc1x _18qlyvc3 _18qlyvca').a.get('href')
            pekerjaan = jobs.find('h1',class_='sx2jih0 zcydq84u _18qlyvc0 _18qlyvc1x _18qlyvc3 _18qlyvca').a.text

            company =  jobs.find('span',class_=re.compile("^sx2jih0 zcydq84u")).text
                                 
            location =  jobs.find('span',class_='sx2jih0 zcydq84u _18qlyvc0 _18qlyvc1x _18qlyvc3 _18qlyvc7').span.text
            published = jobs.find('time',class_='sx2jih0 zcydq84u').get('datetime')
            pub = jobs.find('time',class_='sx2jih0 zcydq84u').text
            sheet.append([pekerjaan,link_job,company,location,published,pub])
            print('=====================',pages)
            print("Job : ",pekerjaan,'\n',"link Job : ",link_job,'\n',"company : ",company,'\n',"location",location,'\n',"published : ",pub,'\n',"published at : ",published)
```